# Maui List<Model> BindableProperty nok working?

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to create my own SegmentedController in a .net Maui application. The bindings and the view(segmented controller) is working correctly when nested inside the page itself.

[image: Bindings working correctly]

But moving the Segmented Controller to it's own view/class component, and creating bindable properties the list is never received/showed as expected.

[image: Bindings not working]

Any clues of what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:
My SegmentedControllerComponent Codebehind class:

```cs
public partial class SegmentedControllerComponent : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ListOfValuesProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ListOfValues), 
            typeof(List<MyModel>), 
            typeof(SegmentedControllerComponent), 
            new List<MyModel>());

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedValueProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedValue), 
            typeof(MyModel), 
            typeof(SegmentedControllerComponent), 
            null);

    public List<MyModel> ListOfValues
    {
        get => (List<MyModel>) GetValue(ListOfValuesProperty);
        set => SetValue(ListOfValuesProperty, value);
    }

    public MyModel SelectedValue
    {
        get => (MyModel)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value);
    }

    public void ValueCheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ratingValue = sender as RadioButton;
        if(ratingValue.IsChecked)
        {
            SelectedValue = ListOfValues.Find(x => x.Value == (string)ratingValue.Value);
        }
    }

    public SegmentedControllerComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

SegmentedControllerComponent view:

```xml
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:App.Model"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
    x:Class="App.SegmentedControllerComponent"
    x:Name="SegmentedControllerName"
    x:DataType="local:SegmentedControllerComponent">
    <Frame 
        CornerRadius="0"
        BorderColor="{x:StaticResource primary-color-gray }"
        BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource primary-color-gray }"
        Padding="0"
        Margin="0,10,0,0"
        HasShadow="false">
        <FlexLayout 
            BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource whitesmoke}"
            Padding="0"
            Margin="0"
            x:Name="RadioButtonGroupName"
            RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="RatingValues"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfValues}"
            RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue.Value}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate 
                    x:DataType="Model:MyModel">
                    <RadioButton
                        Margin="0"
                        Padding="0"
                        FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                        Value="{Binding Value}"
                        Content="{Binding Label}">
                        <RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <VerticalStackLayout>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter
                                                        TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                        Property="Label.BackgroundColor"
                                                        Value="{x:StaticResource color-accent}"/>
                                                        <Setter 
                                                        TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                        Property="Label.FontAttributes"
                                                        Value="Bold"/>
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>

                                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                                        <Setter
                                                            TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                            Property="Label.BackgroundColor"
                                                            Value="{x:StaticResource primary-color-white}"/>
                                                        <Setter 
                                                            TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                            Property="Label.FontAttributes"
                                                            Value="None"/>
                                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        x:Name="TextLabel"
                                        HeightRequest="44"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        TextColor="Black"/>
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                    </RadioButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

How it's referenced in the page.xaml:

```xml
<local:SegmentedControllerComponent 
   ListOfValues="{Binding MyListWithValues}"
   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that actually worked. 
Setting the binding context in the view, instead of the constructor, thanks for the headsup @SirRufo